# problem- 852 leetcode why my code is exceeding time limit

Tags: arrays, while-loop

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int peakIndexInMountainArray(vector<int>& arr) {
        int s=0;
        int e = arr.size() - 1;

        int mid = s+ (e-s)/2;

        while(s<=e){
            if(arr[mid-1]< arr[mid] && arr[mid]> arr[mid+1]){
                return mid;
            }  
           else if(arr[mid]< arr[mid+1]){
                s = mid +1;
            }
           else{
                e= mid-1;
           }
     
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```

I just solved this question and it can run on all test cases but on submission, it results as TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED.
Please help me to figure out what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're using (I assume that's C++). Also: that code can't work, you only ever read `mid` inside the loop, but only ever change `s` and `e` inside the loop, not `mid`. So if it works with the examples, then they have to be tiny or you got insanely lucky somehow.

Answer (score 0):

`mid` should be declared inside the `while` loop so that you take the midpoint of the current interval on each iteration. Note that you can use [`std::midpoint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/midpoint) (instead of `s+ (e-s)/2`) since C++ 20 to avoid overflow issues.

To avoid accessing indexes out of bounds, you should binary search from index `1` to `arr.size() - 2` as the peak index can never be one of the array endpoints.

```cpp
int s = 1, e = arr.size() - 2;
while (s <= e){
    int mid = std::midpoint(s, e);
    // the rest of your code stays the same
}
```

Note that your code can be simplified by only checking the next element instead of also considering the previous element.

```cpp
int l = 1, r = arr.size() - 2;
while (l <= r) {
    int m = std::midpoint(l, r);
    if (arr[m] < arr[m + 1]) l = m + 1;
    else r = m - 1;
}
return l;
```